# jquery - mousemove: how to prevent div to stop follow the mouse

Tags: jquery, html, mousemove

I have 2 div’s. One big yellow box and one small red box. I use jQuery to append the mousemove effect on the yellow box. When the mouse is over the yellow box, the mouseover causes the red box to follow the mouse. When then mouse reaches the red box “in” the yellow box, is no longer  on mousemove on the yellow box and the red box stops follow the mouse. When the mouse enter the yellow box again it move with the mouse again – of course. The red box have to follow the mouse as long it is over the yellow box and not stop because it move over the red box itself. Is there a way to prevent that?

Thanks

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Illum/pPn3v/

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#box1 {width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: Yellow; border: 2px solid Blue;}
#box2 {width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; border: 2px solid pink; z-index: 100; position: absolute;}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#box1").bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        $("#box2").css("left", e.pageX);
        $("#box2").css("top", e.pageY);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is due to the way events bubble. When your cursor is inside of the red box, the yellow box isn't receiving mousemove triggers. Now, if you move box2 to be inside of box1, it will work how you want it to (I believe).

Comment: By move, I mean nest the box2 div inside of the box1 div: `<div id="box1"><div id="box2"></div></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a solution to your problem [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/pPn3v/12/). It may not be the cleanest solution, but it's the only way I can think of accomplishing the task without embedding the div's inside one another.

I have basically added another listener to the "red" box that checks if it is still within the yellow box.

```
var yellow = $('#yellow');
var offset = yellow.offset();
var offsetWidth = offset.left + yellow.width();
var offsetHeight = offset.top + yellow.height();

var red = $('#red');

yellow.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    red.css("left", e.pageX);
    red.css("top", e.pageY);
});

red.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if(e.pageX >= offset.left && e.pageY >= offset.top &&
       e.pageX <= offsetWidth && e.pageY <= offsetHeight) {
        red.css("left", e.pageX);
        red.css("top", e.pageY);  
    }               
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You made two independent divs.
If you make the red div part of the yellow it will work for you.
Change `<div id="box1"></div><div id="box2"></div>` to `<div id="box1"><div id="box2"></div></div>`